# Modify active table Cell Gradient

Tags: vba, gradient, powerpoint

I'm trying to adjust the gradient & fill settings of the selected cell within the selected table.

I've done this with Excel. For PowerPoint the best I've managed is to adjust single fill color. I have been reading various sites but not made any progress. How can I generate the identical effect created in the Excel code below?

Excel Code: (Working)

```
ActiveCell.Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
    .Gradient.Degree = 90
    .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
End With
With Selection.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0)
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
With Selection.Interior.Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1)
    .Color = 39372
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

---

*Edit: Got it working a little bit but still not 100% happy with the colors.

PowerPoint code (WIP)

```
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim oTbl As Table
Dim lRow As Long ' your i
Dim lCol As Long ' your j
Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
Set oTbl = oSh.Table

With oTbl
    For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
        For lCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
            If .Cell(lRow, lCol).Selected Then
                With .Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape
                    .Fill.TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 1
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 222, 129)
                    .Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(208, 154, 0)
                End With
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you got it working. If you don't like the RGB colours you've used, I'd design the style in the PowerPoint UI first and then code what you've designed. To have a multi-stop (more than 2) gradient, you can add stops like this:

```
Sub TableCellGradient()
  Dim oSh As Shape
  Dim oTbl As Table
  Dim lRow As Long ' your i
  Dim lCol As Long ' your j
  Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
  Set oTbl = oSh.Table

  With oTbl
    For lRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
      For lCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
        If .Cell(lRow, lCol).Selected Then
          With .Cell(lRow, lCol).Shape.Fill
            .TwoColorGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 1
            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 222, 129)
            .BackColor.RGB = RGB(208, 154, 0)
            .GradientStops.Insert RGB(255, 255, 255), 0.5, 1
          End With
        End If
      Next
    Next
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: awesome thank you, still wasn't clear on how to add additional stops, that cleared it up for me.

Comment: Yeah - sometimes you'd think the suite of Office apps were designed by different companies, which in Microsoft's defence, they were at the beginning.